# Error en linea comentada en HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel

Estoy trabajando en Laravel y estoy utilizando unas lineas en html pero me da error en la linea 77
    `C:\laragon\www\Proyecto\resources\views/layouts/mi-tema.blade.php:77`
pero esa linea yo la tengo comentada. HTML toma en cuenta aquellos comentarios? o que hice mal?

```
<!--<li class="nav-item">
          @if(Auth::user()->email == "sergiop@gmail.com" )
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ route('pelicula.create') }}">Catálogo</a>
          @else
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ route('pelicula.index') }}">Catálogo</a>
          @endif
</li>-->
```

Este es mi código, está comentado pero el error me lo marca ahí

Error: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object

Comment: Muestra tu código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Coloca el error tambien, y los comentarios de qué forma los has puesto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comentario para las plantillas blade de laravel es:

```
{{-- bla bla bla --}}
```

Mientras que el comentario de html sólo comentará las etiquetas html que haya dentro de ellas (pero no el código php), las etiquetas de blade {{-- --}} comentarán ambos.

Es decir:

En este caso, el contenido PHP se procesará:

```
    <!-- <li class="nav-item">
          @if(Auth::user()->email == "sergiop@gmail.com" )
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ route('pelicula.create') }}">Catálogo</a>
          @else
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ route('pelicula.index') }}">Catálogo</a>
          @endif
</li> -->
```

Dicho esto, necesitarias comentar de esta forma:

```
{{-- <li class="nav-item">
          @if(Auth::user()->email == "sergiop@gmail.com" )
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ route('pelicula.create') }}">Catálogo</a>
          @else
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ route('pelicula.index') }}">Catálogo</a>
          @endif
</li> --}}
```

Comment: Perfecto josé Bardales, eso es basicamente lo que quería, el error ya lo arreglaré después, es que necesito cambiar las rutas y varios nombres